# WDS capture creates 2 .WIMs

Tags: deployment, wds, image, wim

When I capture an image, it successfully captures and deploys with out an issue. But the capture creates 2 entries on the server and 2 .wim files. One is always large(around 20-30 GB) and the other is very small(5-10 MB). They are named the same, but with a '(1)' at end of the smaller file.
 
Questions:
How can I prevent this from happening?
Both seem to work when I deploy them, does it matter which one I keep?
Output form `DISM /Get-ImageInfo` is the same for both:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Details for image : M92P_Base_Win7x64.wim

Index : 1
Name : M92P_Base_Win7x64
Description : All windows updates as of 9-15-2016
Size : 19,812,026,525 bytes

The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: How many partitions do you have on the machine to be imaged? Also, have you thought about VHD imaging?

Comment: Two, I believe. That would make sense, but even I delete the larger .wim I can still use the smaller one to deploy the same image. The 'Expanded Size" on the server is the same for both.

Comment: Does it actually delete the files from the reminstall folder or does it just delete the image index?

Comment: Oh, also is there a raid setup? E.g. mirroring?

Comment: I does delete it from the remoteinstall folder. Not raid or mirroring.

Comment: Can you give me the `imagex /info` output (or dism equivalent) on each of the image files? (please put them output in your question as code) thanks!

Comment: Can you use a windows 10 based image to image your system? (boot from the windows 10 boot wim to image the system) Thanks!

Comment: I have used both win7 and win10

Comment: Hmmm, can you post the WDS log output from the booted capture system and from the wds server? Thanks!